# discerning between further on, further, and more when talking about time

Tags: adverbs

> This company will be continue for ten years **further on**.
>
> This company will be continue for ten years **more**.
>
> This company will be continue for ten years **further**.

Would you please explain what is the difference between those? especially the bold part.

Comment: You seem very confused by this word [_further_](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3751+further).

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that none of those sentences are grammatically correct; 'be continue' does not make sense and should be replaced with just 'continue'.

> This company will continue for ten years **more.**

'Further' and 'further on' imply physical movement, rather than duration. 'More' can work with both duration and physical movement. However, it's common practice to place 'more' before the units and after the number:

> This company will continue for ten **more** years.

But 'further' or 'further on' always go after both the number and unit:

> The marathon runner could see the finish line, just ten yards **further.**